# Can I use artifactory as a local npm cache?

Tags: node.js, artifactory

How do I use artifactory to cache my node modules that way when jenkins runs the npm install command it tries to retrieve the modules from artifactory first, and if it fails it retrieves it from the internet?

How does artifactory work? From what I understand, when you run npm install X, artifactory will see if it has X module if not it retrieves it from the npm registry. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does artifactory work? From what I understand, when you run npm
>   install X, artifactory will see if it has X module if not it retrieves
>   it from the npm registry. Am I correct?

You are correct. Artifactory proxies remote npm repositories like https://registry.npmjs.org, isolating you from network issues, providing reproducible builds and speeding up the builds by retrieving the dependencies from local network.

> How do I use artifactory to cache my node modules that way when
>   jenkins runs the npm install command it tries to retrieve the modules
>   from artifactory first, and if it fails it retrieves it from the
>   internet?

Please follow the instructions in [the User Manual](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Repositories). Generally, you'll set the registry to resolve from by running `npm config set registry http://hostname:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo`, where `npm-repo` will be remote or (even better) virtual repository.

Also please note that you don't need to configure the failover to "the internet", since Artifactory (if configured correctly), exposes all the content of remote repositories, so you will never encounter a situation where something is not found in Artifactory, but can be resolved from a remote repository configured in Artifactory.

Comment: I'm running the open source 4.2 version of artifactory and its not letting me set npm as package type. do you happen to know how to have npm selected as the package type for a remote repo?

Comment: Npm is a part of the Pro version of Artifactory.

Comment: what is the difference between a remote repository and a virtual one?

Comment: Virtual repository aggregates other ones (remote and local) under a single URL that you configure your npm tool to work with.